# Rainbow Text Hover CSS

Tags: jquery, css

- Create custom CSS class where individual letters change color - cycling through the rainbow gradient.
- **Transitions:** 0ms in / 300ms fade out.
- **No links:** To be a CSS class called “rainbow” that I can selectively apply as needed.

**Code:** This is what I have tried.

```js
// add animation-delay properties to span elements

var animTime = 6,   // time for the animation in seconds
    hueChange = 3,   // the hue change from one span element to the next
    prefixes = ["","-webkit-","-moz-","-o-"],
    numPrefixes = prefixes.length;

$('.unicorn').find('span').each(function (i) {
    for (var j=0;j<numPrefixes;j++) {
        $(this).css(prefixes[j]+'animation-delay', (animTime * ((i * hueChange) % 360) / 360) - animTime + 's');
    }
});
```

```css
.unicorn:hover span {
        
    -webkit-animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
     -moz-animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
       -o-animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
          animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
    
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="unicorn"> <span style="color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);">L</span><span style="color: hsl(4, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(7, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(10, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(13, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(16, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(19, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(23, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(26, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(29, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(32, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(35, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(38, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(42, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(45, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(48, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(51, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(54, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(57, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(60, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(64, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(67, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(70, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(73, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(76, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(79, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(83, 100%, 50%);">,</span><span style="color: hsl(86, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(89, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(92, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(95, 100%, 50%);">n</span><span style="color: hsl(98, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(102, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(105, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(108, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(111, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(114, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(117, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(124, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(127, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(130, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(133, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(136, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(139, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(143, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(146, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(149, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(152, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(155, 100%, 50%);">n</span><span style="color: hsl(158, 100%, 50%);">g</span><span style="color: hsl(162, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(165, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(168, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(171, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(174, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(177, 100%, 50%);">.</span><span style="color: hsl(180, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(184, 100%, 50%);">C</span><span style="color: hsl(187, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(190, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(193, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(196, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(199, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(203, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(206, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(209, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(212, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(215, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(218, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(222, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(225, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(228, 100%, 50%);">q</span><span style="color: hsl(231, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(234, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(237, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(244, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(247, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(250, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(253, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(256, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(259, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(263, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(266, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(269, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(272, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(275, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(278, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(282, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(285, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(288, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(291, 100%, 50%);">q</span><span style="color: hsl(294, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(297, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(300, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(304, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(307, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(310, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(313, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(316, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(319, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(323, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(326, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(329, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(332, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(335, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(338, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(342, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(345, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(348, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(351, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(354, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(357, 100%, 50%);">i</span>

</p>
```

Does anyone has any idea about making it. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You should give it some try before asking

Comment: Try something, code something, show us and then ask.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P6WVg/7/ I have tried this

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bizakogira/edit?html,js,output this also but i need something different

Comment: I need a pure css version of it

Comment: @ToanLu Just drawing attention now that there is code.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Just drawing attention now that there is code.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS. I am nearly 4 years late to this but, I've only done it for @keyframes and I've used my own pastel colours but as long as you have 25 colours you can do a search and replace for each html colour code i've used to swap in your own colours. Also I've given you a choice of going forwards or backwards depending on what you're after, you can also amend the 90 degrees I've used with a simple search and replace all.

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate aliquid maiores doloremque molestiae corruption</h1>
```

css:

```
h1 {
    color: transparent;
    animation: colourRotateForwards 2s linear infinite
}

@keyframes backColourRotate {
    from {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7575 0%, #ff9875 4%, #ffba75 8%, #ffdd75 12%, #ffff75 16%, #ddff75 20%, #baff75 24%, #98ff75 28%, #75ff75 32%, #75ff98 36%, #75ffba 40%, #75ffdd 44%, #75ffff 48%, #75ddff 52%, #75baff 56%, #7598ff 60%, #7575ff 64%, #9875ff 68%, #ba75ff 72%, #dd75ff 76%, #ff75ff 80%, #ff75dd 84%, #ff75ba 88%, #ff7598 92%, #ff7575 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    4% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9875 0%, #ffba75 4%, #ffdd75 8%, #ffff75 12%, #ddff75 16%, #baff75 20%, #98ff75 24%, #75ff75 28%, #75ff98 32%, #75ffba 36%, #75ffdd 40%, #75ffff 44%, #75ddff 48%, #75baff 52%, #7598ff 56%, #7575ff 60%, #9875ff 64%, #ba75ff 68%, #dd75ff 72%, #ff75ff 76%, #ff75dd 80%, #ff75ba 84%, #ff7598 88%, #ff7575 92%, #ff7575 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    8% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffba75 0%, #ffdd75 4%, #ffff75 8%, #ddff75 12%, #baff75 16%, #98ff75 20%, #75ff75 24%, #75ff98 28%, #75ffba 32%, #75ffdd 36%, #75ffff 40%, #75ddff 44%, #75baff 48%, #7598ff 52%, #7575ff 56%, #9875ff 60%, #ba75ff 64%, #dd75ff 68%, #ff75ff 72%, #ff75dd 76%, #ff75ba 80%, #ff7598 84%, #ff7575 88%, #ff7575 92%, #ff9875 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    12% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffdd75 0%, #ffff75 4%, #ddff75 8%, #baff75 12%, #98ff75 16%, #75ff75 20%, #75ff98 24%, #75ffba 28%, #75ffdd 32%, #75ffff 36%, #75ddff 40%, #75baff 44%, #7598ff 48%, #7575ff 52%, #9875ff 56%, #ba75ff 60%, #dd75ff 64%, #ff75ff 68%, #ff75dd 72%, #ff75ba 76%, #ff7598 80%, #ff7575 84%, #ff7575 88%, #ff9875 92%, #ffba75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    16% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffff75 0%, #ddff75 4%, #baff75 8%, #98ff75 12%, #75ff75 16%, #75ff98 20%, #75ffba 24%, #75ffdd 28%, #75ffff 32%, #75ddff 36%, #75baff 40%, #7598ff 44%, #7575ff 48%, #9875ff 52%, #ba75ff 56%, #dd75ff 60%, #ff75ff 64%, #ff75dd 68%, #ff75ba 72%, #ff7598 76%, #ff7575 80%, #ff7575 84%, #ff9875 88%, #ffba75 92%, #ffdd75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    20% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddff75 0%, #baff75 4%, #98ff75 8%, #75ff75 12%, #75ff98 16%, #75ffba 20%, #75ffdd 24%, #75ffff 28%, #75ddff 32%, #75baff 36%, #7598ff 40%, #7575ff 44%, #9875ff 48%, #ba75ff 52%, #dd75ff 56%, #ff75ff 60%, #ff75dd 64%, #ff75ba 68%, #ff7598 72%, #ff7575 76%, #ff7575 80%, #ff9875 84%, #ffba75 88%, #ffdd75 92%, #ffff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    24% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #baff75 0%, #98ff75 4%, #75ff75 8%, #75ff98 12%, #75ffba 16%, #75ffdd 20%, #75ffff 24%, #75ddff 28%, #75baff 32%, #7598ff 36%, #7575ff 40%, #9875ff 44%, #ba75ff 48%, #dd75ff 52%, #ff75ff 56%, #ff75dd 60%, #ff75ba 64%, #ff7598 68%, #ff7575 72%, #ff7575 76%, #ff9875 80%, #ffba75 84%, #ffdd75 88%, #ffff75 92%, #ddff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    28% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #98ff75 0%, #75ff75 4%, #75ff98 8%, #75ffba 12%, #75ffdd 16%, #75ffff 20%, #75ddff 24%, #75baff 28%, #7598ff 32%, #7575ff 36%, #9875ff 40%, #ba75ff 44%, #dd75ff 48%, #ff75ff 52%, #ff75dd 56%, #ff75ba 60%, #ff7598 64%, #ff7575 68%, #ff7575 72%, #ff9875 76%, #ffba75 80%, #ffdd75 84%, #ffff75 88%, #ddff75 92%, #baff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    32% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ff75 0%, #75ff98 4%, #75ffba 8%, #75ffdd 12%, #75ffff 16%, #75ddff 20%, #75baff 24%, #7598ff 28%, #7575ff 32%, #9875ff 36%, #ba75ff 40%, #dd75ff 44%, #ff75ff 48%, #ff75dd 52%, #ff75ba 56%, #ff7598 60%, #ff7575 64%, #ff7575 68%, #ff9875 72%, #ffba75 76%, #ffdd75 80%, #ffff75 84%, #ddff75 88%, #baff75 92%, #98ff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    36% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ff98 0%, #75ffba 4%, #75ffdd 8%, #75ffff 12%, #75ddff 16%, #75baff 20%, #7598ff 24%, #7575ff 28%, #9875ff 32%, #ba75ff 36%, #dd75ff 40%, #ff75ff 44%, #ff75dd 48%, #ff75ba 52%, #ff7598 56%, #ff7575 60%, #ff7575 64%, #ff9875 68%, #ffba75 72%, #ffdd75 76%, #ffff75 80%, #ddff75 84%, #baff75 88%, #98ff75 92%, #75ff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    40% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ffba 0%, #75ffdd 4%, #75ffff 8%, #75ddff 12%, #75baff 16%, #7598ff 20%, #7575ff 24%, #9875ff 28%, #ba75ff 32%, #dd75ff 36%, #ff75ff 40%, #ff75dd 44%, #ff75ba 48%, #ff7598 52%, #ff7575 56%, #ff7575 60%, #ff9875 64%, #ffba75 68%, #ffdd75 72%, #ffff75 76%, #ddff75 80%, #baff75 84%, #98ff75 88%, #75ff75 92%, #75ff98 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    44% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ffdd 0%, #75ffff 4%, #75ddff 8%, #75baff 12%, #7598ff 16%, #7575ff 20%, #9875ff 24%, #ba75ff 28%, #dd75ff 32%, #ff75ff 36%, #ff75dd 40%, #ff75ba 44%, #ff7598 48%, #ff7575 52%, #ff7575 56%, #ff9875 60%, #ffba75 64%, #ffdd75 68%, #ffff75 72%, #ddff75 76%, #baff75 80%, #98ff75 84%, #75ff75 88%, #75ff98 92%, #75ffba 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    48% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ffff 0%, #75ddff 4%, #75baff 8%, #7598ff 12%, #7575ff 16%, #9875ff 20%, #ba75ff 24%, #dd75ff 28%, #ff75ff 32%, #ff75dd 36%, #ff75ba 40%, #ff7598 44%, #ff7575 48%, #ff7575 52%, #ff9875 56%, #ffba75 60%, #ffdd75 64%, #ffff75 68%, #ddff75 72%, #baff75 76%, #98ff75 80%, #75ff75 84%, #75ff98 88%, #75ffba 92%, #75ffdd 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    52% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ddff 0%, #75baff 4%, #7598ff 8%, #7575ff 12%, #9875ff 16%, #ba75ff 20%, #dd75ff 24%, #ff75ff 28%, #ff75dd 32%, #ff75ba 36%, #ff7598 40%, #ff7575 44%, #ff7575 48%, #ff9875 52%, #ffba75 56%, #ffdd75 60%, #ffff75 64%, #ddff75 68%, #baff75 72%, #98ff75 76%, #75ff75 80%, #75ff98 84%, #75ffba 88%, #75ffdd 92%, #75ffff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    56% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75baff 0%, #7598ff 4%, #7575ff 8%, #9875ff 12%, #ba75ff 16%, #dd75ff 20%, #ff75ff 24%, #ff75dd 28%, #ff75ba 32%, #ff7598 36%, #ff7575 40%, #ff7575 44%, #ff9875 48%, #ffba75 52%, #ffdd75 56%, #ffff75 60%, #ddff75 64%, #baff75 68%, #98ff75 72%, #75ff75 76%, #75ff98 80%, #75ffba 84%, #75ffdd 88%, #75ffff 92%, #75ddff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    60% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7598ff 0%, #7575ff 4%, #9875ff 8%, #ba75ff 12%, #dd75ff 16%, #ff75ff 20%, #ff75dd 24%, #ff75ba 28%, #ff7598 32%, #ff7575 36%, #ff7575 40%, #ff9875 44%, #ffba75 48%, #ffdd75 52%, #ffff75 56%, #ddff75 60%, #baff75 64%, #98ff75 68%, #75ff75 72%, #75ff98 76%, #75ffba 80%, #75ffdd 84%, #75ffff 88%, #75ddff 92%, #75baff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    64% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7575ff 0%, #9875ff 4%, #ba75ff 8%, #dd75ff 12%, #ff75ff 16%, #ff75dd 20%, #ff75ba 24%, #ff7598 28%, #ff7575 32%, #ff7575 36%, #ff9875 40%, #ffba75 44%, #ffdd75 48%, #ffff75 52%, #ddff75 56%, #baff75 60%, #98ff75 64%, #75ff75 68%, #75ff98 72%, #75ffba 76%, #75ffdd 80%, #75ffff 84%, #75ddff 88%, #75baff 92%, #7598ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    68% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #9875ff 0%, #ba75ff 4%, #dd75ff 8%, #ff75ff 12%, #ff75dd 16%, #ff75ba 20%, #ff7598 24%, #ff7575 28%, #ff7575 32%, #ff9875 36%, #ffba75 40%, #ffdd75 44%, #ffff75 48%, #ddff75 52%, #baff75 56%, #98ff75 60%, #75ff75 64%, #75ff98 68%, #75ffba 72%, #75ffdd 76%, #75ffff 80%, #75ddff 84%, #75baff 88%, #7598ff 92%, #7575ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    72% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ba75ff 0%, #dd75ff 4%, #ff75ff 8%, #ff75dd 12%, #ff75ba 16%, #ff7598 20%, #ff7575 24%, #ff7575 28%, #ff9875 32%, #ffba75 36%, #ffdd75 40%, #ffff75 44%, #ddff75 48%, #baff75 52%, #98ff75 56%, #75ff75 60%, #75ff98 64%, #75ffba 68%, #75ffdd 72%, #75ffff 76%, #75ddff 80%, #75baff 84%, #7598ff 88%, #7575ff 92%, #9875ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    76% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #dd75ff 0%, #ff75ff 4%, #ff75dd 8%, #ff75ba 12%, #ff7598 16%, #ff7575 20%, #ff7575 24%, #ff9875 28%, #ffba75 32%, #ffdd75 36%, #ffff75 40%, #ddff75 44%, #baff75 48%, #98ff75 52%, #75ff75 56%, #75ff98 60%, #75ffba 64%, #75ffdd 68%, #75ffff 72%, #75ddff 76%, #75baff 80%, #7598ff 84%, #7575ff 88%, #9875ff 92%, #ba75ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    80% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff75ff 0%, #ff75dd 4%, #ff75ba 8%, #ff7598 12%, #ff7575 16%, #ff7575 20%, #ff9875 24%, #ffba75 28%, #ffdd75 32%, #ffff75 36%, #ddff75 40%, #baff75 44%, #98ff75 48%, #75ff75 52%, #75ff98 56%, #75ffba 60%, #75ffdd 64%, #75ffff 68%, #75ddff 72%, #75baff 76%, #7598ff 80%, #7575ff 84%, #9875ff 88%, #ba75ff 92%, #dd75ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    84% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff75dd 0%, #ff75ba 4%, #ff7598 8%, #ff7575 12%, #ff7575 16%, #ff9875 20%, #ffba75 24%, #ffdd75 28%, #ffff75 32%, #ddff75 36%, #baff75 40%, #98ff75 44%, #75ff75 48%, #75ff98 52%, #75ffba 56%, #75ffdd 60%, #75ffff 64%, #75ddff 68%, #75baff 72%, #7598ff 76%, #7575ff 80%, #9875ff 84%, #ba75ff 88%, #dd75ff 92%, #ff75ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    88% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff75ba 0%, #ff7598 4%, #ff7575 8%, #ff7575 12%, #ff9875 16%, #ffba75 20%, #ffdd75 24%, #ffff75 28%, #ddff75 32%, #baff75 36%, #98ff75 40%, #75ff75 44%, #75ff98 48%, #75ffba 52%, #75ffdd 56%, #75ffff 60%, #75ddff 64%, #75baff 68%, #7598ff 72%, #7575ff 76%, #9875ff 80%, #ba75ff 84%, #dd75ff 88%, #ff75ff 92%, #ff75dd 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    92% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7598 0%, #ff7575 4%, #ff7575 8%, #ff9875 12%, #ffba75 16%, #ffdd75 20%, #ffff75 24%, #ddff75 28%, #baff75 32%, #98ff75 36%, #75ff75 40%, #75ff98 44%, #75ffba 48%, #75ffdd 52%, #75ffff 56%, #75ddff 60%, #75baff 64%, #7598ff 68%, #7575ff 72%, #9875ff 76%, #ba75ff 80%, #dd75ff 84%, #ff75ff 88%, #ff75dd 92%, #ff75ba 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    96% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7575 0%, #ff7575 4%, #ff9875 8%, #ffba75 12%, #ffdd75 16%, #ffff75 20%, #ddff75 24%, #baff75 28%, #98ff75 32%, #75ff75 36%, #75ff98 40%, #75ffba 44%, #75ffdd 48%, #75ffff 52%, #75ddff 56%, #75baff 60%, #7598ff 64%, #7575ff 68%, #9875ff 72%, #ba75ff 76%, #dd75ff 80%, #ff75ff 84%, #ff75dd 88%, #ff75ba 92%, #ff7598 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    to {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7575 0%, #ff9875 4%, #ffba75 8%, #ffdd75 12%, #ffff75 16%, #ddff75 20%, #baff75 24%, #98ff75 28%, #75ff75 32%, #75ff98 36%, #75ffba 40%, #75ffdd 44%, #75ffff 48%, #75ddff 52%, #75baff 56%, #7598ff 60%, #7575ff 64%, #9875ff 68%, #ba75ff 72%, #dd75ff 76%, #ff75ff 80%, #ff75dd 84%, #ff75ba 88%, #ff7598 92%, #ff7575 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
}

@keyframes colourRotateForwards {
    from {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7575 0%, #ff9875 4%, #ffba75 8%, #ffdd75 12%, #ffff75 16%, #ddff75 20%, #baff75 24%, #98ff75 28%, #75ff75 32%, #75ff98 36%, #75ffba 40%, #75ffdd 44%, #75ffff 48%, #75ddff 52%, #75baff 56%, #7598ff 60%, #7575ff 64%, #9875ff 68%, #ba75ff 72%, #dd75ff 76%, #ff75ff 80%, #ff75dd 84%, #ff75ba 88%, #ff7598 92%, #ff7575 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    4% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7575 0%, #ff7575 4%, #ff9875 8%, #ffba75 12%, #ffdd75 16%, #ffff75 20%, #ddff75 24%, #baff75 28%, #98ff75 32%, #75ff75 36%, #75ff98 40%, #75ffba 44%, #75ffdd 48%, #75ffff 52%, #75ddff 56%, #75baff 60%, #7598ff 64%, #7575ff 68%, #9875ff 72%, #ba75ff 76%, #dd75ff 80%, #ff75ff 84%, #ff75dd 88%, #ff75ba 92%, #ff7598 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    8% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7598 0%, #ff7575 4%, #ff7575 8%, #ff9875 12%, #ffba75 16%, #ffdd75 20%, #ffff75 24%, #ddff75 28%, #baff75 32%, #98ff75 36%, #75ff75 40%, #75ff98 44%, #75ffba 48%, #75ffdd 52%, #75ffff 56%, #75ddff 60%, #75baff 64%, #7598ff 68%, #7575ff 72%, #9875ff 76%, #ba75ff 80%, #dd75ff 84%, #ff75ff 88%, #ff75dd 92%, #ff75ba 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    12% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff75ba 0%, #ff7598 4%, #ff7575 8%, #ff7575 12%, #ff9875 16%, #ffba75 20%, #ffdd75 24%, #ffff75 28%, #ddff75 32%, #baff75 36%, #98ff75 40%, #75ff75 44%, #75ff98 48%, #75ffba 52%, #75ffdd 56%, #75ffff 60%, #75ddff 64%, #75baff 68%, #7598ff 72%, #7575ff 76%, #9875ff 80%, #ba75ff 84%, #dd75ff 88%, #ff75ff 92%, #ff75dd 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    16% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff75dd 0%, #ff75ba 4%, #ff7598 8%, #ff7575 12%, #ff7575 16%, #ff9875 20%, #ffba75 24%, #ffdd75 28%, #ffff75 32%, #ddff75 36%, #baff75 40%, #98ff75 44%, #75ff75 48%, #75ff98 52%, #75ffba 56%, #75ffdd 60%, #75ffff 64%, #75ddff 68%, #75baff 72%, #7598ff 76%, #7575ff 80%, #9875ff 84%, #ba75ff 88%, #dd75ff 92%, #ff75ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    20% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff75ff 0%, #ff75dd 4%, #ff75ba 8%, #ff7598 12%, #ff7575 16%, #ff7575 20%, #ff9875 24%, #ffba75 28%, #ffdd75 32%, #ffff75 36%, #ddff75 40%, #baff75 44%, #98ff75 48%, #75ff75 52%, #75ff98 56%, #75ffba 60%, #75ffdd 64%, #75ffff 68%, #75ddff 72%, #75baff 76%, #7598ff 80%, #7575ff 84%, #9875ff 88%, #ba75ff 92%, #dd75ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    24% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #dd75ff 0%, #ff75ff 4%, #ff75dd 8%, #ff75ba 12%, #ff7598 16%, #ff7575 20%, #ff7575 24%, #ff9875 28%, #ffba75 32%, #ffdd75 36%, #ffff75 40%, #ddff75 44%, #baff75 48%, #98ff75 52%, #75ff75 56%, #75ff98 60%, #75ffba 64%, #75ffdd 68%, #75ffff 72%, #75ddff 76%, #75baff 80%, #7598ff 84%, #7575ff 88%, #9875ff 92%, #ba75ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    28% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ba75ff 0%, #dd75ff 4%, #ff75ff 8%, #ff75dd 12%, #ff75ba 16%, #ff7598 20%, #ff7575 24%, #ff7575 28%, #ff9875 32%, #ffba75 36%, #ffdd75 40%, #ffff75 44%, #ddff75 48%, #baff75 52%, #98ff75 56%, #75ff75 60%, #75ff98 64%, #75ffba 68%, #75ffdd 72%, #75ffff 76%, #75ddff 80%, #75baff 84%, #7598ff 88%, #7575ff 92%, #9875ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    32% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #9875ff 0%, #ba75ff 4%, #dd75ff 8%, #ff75ff 12%, #ff75dd 16%, #ff75ba 20%, #ff7598 24%, #ff7575 28%, #ff7575 32%, #ff9875 36%, #ffba75 40%, #ffdd75 44%, #ffff75 48%, #ddff75 52%, #baff75 56%, #98ff75 60%, #75ff75 64%, #75ff98 68%, #75ffba 72%, #75ffdd 76%, #75ffff 80%, #75ddff 84%, #75baff 88%, #7598ff 92%, #7575ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    36% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7575ff 0%, #9875ff 4%, #ba75ff 8%, #dd75ff 12%, #ff75ff 16%, #ff75dd 20%, #ff75ba 24%, #ff7598 28%, #ff7575 32%, #ff7575 36%, #ff9875 40%, #ffba75 44%, #ffdd75 48%, #ffff75 52%, #ddff75 56%, #baff75 60%, #98ff75 64%, #75ff75 68%, #75ff98 72%, #75ffba 76%, #75ffdd 80%, #75ffff 84%, #75ddff 88%, #75baff 92%, #7598ff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    40% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7598ff 0%, #7575ff 4%, #9875ff 8%, #ba75ff 12%, #dd75ff 16%, #ff75ff 20%, #ff75dd 24%, #ff75ba 28%, #ff7598 32%, #ff7575 36%, #ff7575 40%, #ff9875 44%, #ffba75 48%, #ffdd75 52%, #ffff75 56%, #ddff75 60%, #baff75 64%, #98ff75 68%, #75ff75 72%, #75ff98 76%, #75ffba 80%, #75ffdd 84%, #75ffff 88%, #75ddff 92%, #75baff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    44% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75baff 0%, #7598ff 4%, #7575ff 8%, #9875ff 12%, #ba75ff 16%, #dd75ff 20%, #ff75ff 24%, #ff75dd 28%, #ff75ba 32%, #ff7598 36%, #ff7575 40%, #ff7575 44%, #ff9875 48%, #ffba75 52%, #ffdd75 56%, #ffff75 60%, #ddff75 64%, #baff75 68%, #98ff75 72%, #75ff75 76%, #75ff98 80%, #75ffba 84%, #75ffdd 88%, #75ffff 92%, #75ddff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    48% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ddff 0%, #75baff 4%, #7598ff 8%, #7575ff 12%, #9875ff 16%, #ba75ff 20%, #dd75ff 24%, #ff75ff 28%, #ff75dd 32%, #ff75ba 36%, #ff7598 40%, #ff7575 44%, #ff7575 48%, #ff9875 52%, #ffba75 56%, #ffdd75 60%, #ffff75 64%, #ddff75 68%, #baff75 72%, #98ff75 76%, #75ff75 80%, #75ff98 84%, #75ffba 88%, #75ffdd 92%, #75ffff 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    52% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ffff 0%, #75ddff 4%, #75baff 8%, #7598ff 12%, #7575ff 16%, #9875ff 20%, #ba75ff 24%, #dd75ff 28%, #ff75ff 32%, #ff75dd 36%, #ff75ba 40%, #ff7598 44%, #ff7575 48%, #ff7575 52%, #ff9875 56%, #ffba75 60%, #ffdd75 64%, #ffff75 68%, #ddff75 72%, #baff75 76%, #98ff75 80%, #75ff75 84%, #75ff98 88%, #75ffba 92%, #75ffdd 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    56% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ffdd 0%, #75ffff 4%, #75ddff 8%, #75baff 12%, #7598ff 16%, #7575ff 20%, #9875ff 24%, #ba75ff 28%, #dd75ff 32%, #ff75ff 36%, #ff75dd 40%, #ff75ba 44%, #ff7598 48%, #ff7575 52%, #ff7575 56%, #ff9875 60%, #ffba75 64%, #ffdd75 68%, #ffff75 72%, #ddff75 76%, #baff75 80%, #98ff75 84%, #75ff75 88%, #75ff98 92%, #75ffba 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    60% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ffba 0%, #75ffdd 4%, #75ffff 8%, #75ddff 12%, #75baff 16%, #7598ff 20%, #7575ff 24%, #9875ff 28%, #ba75ff 32%, #dd75ff 36%, #ff75ff 40%, #ff75dd 44%, #ff75ba 48%, #ff7598 52%, #ff7575 56%, #ff7575 60%, #ff9875 64%, #ffba75 68%, #ffdd75 72%, #ffff75 76%, #ddff75 80%, #baff75 84%, #98ff75 88%, #75ff75 92%, #75ff98 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    64% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ff98 0%, #75ffba 4%, #75ffdd 8%, #75ffff 12%, #75ddff 16%, #75baff 20%, #7598ff 24%, #7575ff 28%, #9875ff 32%, #ba75ff 36%, #dd75ff 40%, #ff75ff 44%, #ff75dd 48%, #ff75ba 52%, #ff7598 56%, #ff7575 60%, #ff7575 64%, #ff9875 68%, #ffba75 72%, #ffdd75 76%, #ffff75 80%, #ddff75 84%, #baff75 88%, #98ff75 92%, #75ff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    68% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #75ff75 0%, #75ff98 4%, #75ffba 8%, #75ffdd 12%, #75ffff 16%, #75ddff 20%, #75baff 24%, #7598ff 28%, #7575ff 32%, #9875ff 36%, #ba75ff 40%, #dd75ff 44%, #ff75ff 48%, #ff75dd 52%, #ff75ba 56%, #ff7598 60%, #ff7575 64%, #ff7575 68%, #ff9875 72%, #ffba75 76%, #ffdd75 80%, #ffff75 84%, #ddff75 88%, #baff75 92%, #98ff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    72% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #98ff75 0%, #75ff75 4%, #75ff98 8%, #75ffba 12%, #75ffdd 16%, #75ffff 20%, #75ddff 24%, #75baff 28%, #7598ff 32%, #7575ff 36%, #9875ff 40%, #ba75ff 44%, #dd75ff 48%, #ff75ff 52%, #ff75dd 56%, #ff75ba 60%, #ff7598 64%, #ff7575 68%, #ff7575 72%, #ff9875 76%, #ffba75 80%, #ffdd75 84%, #ffff75 88%, #ddff75 92%, #baff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    76% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #baff75 0%, #98ff75 4%, #75ff75 8%, #75ff98 12%, #75ffba 16%, #75ffdd 20%, #75ffff 24%, #75ddff 28%, #75baff 32%, #7598ff 36%, #7575ff 40%, #9875ff 44%, #ba75ff 48%, #dd75ff 52%, #ff75ff 56%, #ff75dd 60%, #ff75ba 64%, #ff7598 68%, #ff7575 72%, #ff7575 76%, #ff9875 80%, #ffba75 84%, #ffdd75 88%, #ffff75 92%, #ddff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    80% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddff75 0%, #baff75 4%, #98ff75 8%, #75ff75 12%, #75ff98 16%, #75ffba 20%, #75ffdd 24%, #75ffff 28%, #75ddff 32%, #75baff 36%, #7598ff 40%, #7575ff 44%, #9875ff 48%, #ba75ff 52%, #dd75ff 56%, #ff75ff 60%, #ff75dd 64%, #ff75ba 68%, #ff7598 72%, #ff7575 76%, #ff7575 80%, #ff9875 84%, #ffba75 88%, #ffdd75 92%, #ffff75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    84% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffff75 0%, #ddff75 4%, #baff75 8%, #98ff75 12%, #75ff75 16%, #75ff98 20%, #75ffba 24%, #75ffdd 28%, #75ffff 32%, #75ddff 36%, #75baff 40%, #7598ff 44%, #7575ff 48%, #9875ff 52%, #ba75ff 56%, #dd75ff 60%, #ff75ff 64%, #ff75dd 68%, #ff75ba 72%, #ff7598 76%, #ff7575 80%, #ff7575 84%, #ff9875 88%, #ffba75 92%, #ffdd75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    88% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffdd75 0%, #ffff75 4%, #ddff75 8%, #baff75 12%, #98ff75 16%, #75ff75 20%, #75ff98 24%, #75ffba 28%, #75ffdd 32%, #75ffff 36%, #75ddff 40%, #75baff 44%, #7598ff 48%, #7575ff 52%, #9875ff 56%, #ba75ff 60%, #dd75ff 64%, #ff75ff 68%, #ff75dd 72%, #ff75ba 76%, #ff7598 80%, #ff7575 84%, #ff7575 88%, #ff9875 92%, #ffba75 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    92% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffba75 0%, #ffdd75 4%, #ffff75 8%, #ddff75 12%, #baff75 16%, #98ff75 20%, #75ff75 24%, #75ff98 28%, #75ffba 32%, #75ffdd 36%, #75ffff 40%, #75ddff 44%, #75baff 48%, #7598ff 52%, #7575ff 56%, #9875ff 60%, #ba75ff 64%, #dd75ff 68%, #ff75ff 72%, #ff75dd 76%, #ff75ba 80%, #ff7598 84%, #ff7575 88%, #ff7575 92%, #ff9875 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    96% {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9875 0%, #ffba75 4%, #ffdd75 8%, #ffff75 12%, #ddff75 16%, #baff75 20%, #98ff75 24%, #75ff75 28%, #75ff98 32%, #75ffba 36%, #75ffdd 40%, #75ffff 44%, #75ddff 48%, #75baff 52%, #7598ff 56%, #7575ff 60%, #9875ff 64%, #ba75ff 68%, #dd75ff 72%, #ff75ff 76%, #ff75dd 80%, #ff75ba 84%, #ff7598 88%, #ff7575 92%, #ff7575 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
    to {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff7575 0%, #ff9875 4%, #ffba75 8%, #ffdd75 12%, #ffff75 16%, #ddff75 20%, #baff75 24%, #98ff75 28%, #75ff75 32%, #75ff98 36%, #75ffba 40%, #75ffdd 44%, #75ffff 48%, #75ddff 52%, #75baff 56%, #7598ff 60%, #7575ff 64%, #9875ff 68%, #ba75ff 72%, #dd75ff 76%, #ff75ff 80%, #ff75dd 84%, #ff75ba 88%, #ff7598 92%, #ff7575 96%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text
    }
}
```